# Can you configure Rails to warn you when migrations result in data loss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Things like removing a column result in data loss in Rails. Can you configure it to warn you of these situations (and possibly stop the migration if this happens)? I know Entity Framework does this by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are configurations for Rails to prevent such, however I you can use some gems such as [strong_migrations](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations), to catch these situations. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Nice gem especially for those new to rails

Answer (score 0):

You can also instruct ActiveRecord to simply ignore columns in tables.

```
# For Rails 5+
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.ignored_columns = ["some_column"]
end

# For Rails < 5
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.columns
    super.reject { |c| c.name == "some_column" }
  end
end
```